# linkedlist has two sizes

Tags: java, android, linked-list, accelerometer

I'm trying to add to a LinkedList values from the accelerometer.

```
private LinkedList<Float> rawValues = new LinkedList<Float>();
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    int eventType = event.sensor.getType();

    switch(eventType)
    {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            float accelerometer_z = event.values[2];


                     rawValues.add(accelerometer_z);

                     /**
                      * This printout gives me positions and event values
                      */
                     System.out.println("getAccelerometer size: " +                 
                     rawValues.size() + " entry: " + rawValues.getLast());

            break;
    }
}
```

So far so good, I get readings and number positions as expected.
However, when I'm trying to do stuff with the list in other methods, it appears to be empty!

```
public String[] getVelocity()
{
    String[] velocityString = {"42","42"};
    String values = "";
    String theInteger = "";

    /**
     * Returns a 0 size...
     */
    int theSize = rawValues.size();

    System.out.println("getVelocity size: " + theSize);

    LinkedList<Float> slopeValues = calculateSlopeValues( rawValues);

    for (int i = 0; i < theSize; i++)
    {
        values += "Raw:"+i+ " " + String.valueOf(rawValues.get(i)) + "\n";
        values += "\tSlope:"+i+ " " + String.valueOf(slopeValues.get(i)) + "\n";
    }

    theInteger = String.valueOf(Math.round(Collections.max(slopeValues)*100));

    /**
     * After adding everything to local variables, the list is cleared.
     */
    slopeValues.clear();

    velocityString[0] = theInteger;
    velocityString[1] = values;


    return velocityString;
}
```

getVelocity method is called from the onTouch in the main activity.
Shed some light, please?

Regards
/M

Overridden onTouch method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
{
    MySensorEventListener eventListener = new MySensorEventListener();

    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            String[] strings = eventListener.getVelocity();

            String velocity_int = strings[0];
            String velocity_string = strings[1];


            velocityView.setText(velocity_int);
            listView.setText(velocity_string);


            break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Either you have two different List instances, or you access a unique List instances from two threads without synchonization. It's hard to say with the code you posted.

Comment: I see.. How can I make things more clear to you?

Comment: Try adding `volatile` keyword to rawValues declaration - if it helps use synchronization as written in Java tutorials on Threads.

Comment: By posting more code: which class are these two methods part of? Where are you instantiating this (or these) class(es).

Comment: @Xeon: `volatile` won't make the above code more thread-safe.

Comment: These methods are both parts of the same class. onSensorChanged is android built-in and getVelocity is accessed from onTouch.

Comment: @JB Nizet - added onTouch method and class instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, each time `onTouch()` is called, you create a new instance of `MySensorEventListener`, and ask this new instance for its velocity. Since each `MySensorEventListener` instance has its own linked list of raw values, you get an empty list each time.

The listener should probably be created only once, and stored in an instance field of the enclosing class.

Comment: Ok, I tried putting the eventListener in the main activity class but it still doesn't get it. I've managed to do this in a previous iteration of the program, but then I had the MySensorEventListener class within the main activity class. Now i tried making the MySensorEventListener a separate class file, and therefore I have two instances of the linked list. Can I have them in separate .java files  or is it necessary to have a class within a class in this case?

Comment: Using nested classes or top-level classes doesn't change anything. What matters is how many instances of the listener you create. Put a debug trace in the constructor of your listener. If you see this trace more than once, then it's instanciated multiple times.

Comment: OK, I worked it out now. It seems that I had created two instances of MySensorEventListener class indeed. Strange it didn't give me any hiccups in the previous version tho. Thanks a lot for your support. Have a merry Christmas! ^_^